# viper-mode で vim の ctrl-o 相当のコマンドはあるか。

Tags: emacs, elisp

vim だと、各ジャンプ系のコマンドを実行した際には、そのジャンプ前の位置がスタック的なものに記録されているようで、ctrl+o で元に戻る、 ctrl+i でその逆が実行できます。

emacs で、このような機能はありますか。もしくは、 viper-mode を普段使っているのですが、 viper-mode にこのような機能は実装されていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常モードですが、近そうなのは、C-u C-SPCかC-x C-SPCあたりでしょうか。

Comment: mark も ring になってたんですね。。（知らなかった。)